# Is it possible to show a mapView in a dialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

Here is my code:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_info_with_map);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
```

show_info_with_map is a layout file with a maoView and some textView. I did added the user-library and extended MapActivty. But I am still getting the following error:

`E/AndroidRuntime(23846): android.view.InflateException:`

`Binary XML file line #108:    Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView`

Comment: just for reference, the    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_info_with_map) works perfectly fine without mapView

Comment: can you post your xml file which contains the mapview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your map activity in the manifest, it comes up as a dialog. You can then control how the dialog appears by tweaking your map activity layout

Answer (score 0):

Show your `MapView` in `MapActivity`, just make it look like dialog by applying `Theme.Dialog` to it.

There's no other way. At least with API v1. You can also take a look at [Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)